# Error building gems in Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, nokogiri

I just bought a new MacBook Pro (obviously w/ML). First thing I'm doing is installing development tools. I installed Ruby with rvm and I've also got Homebrew installed. I had to download the XCode command line tools.

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~67/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~67/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

I was able to install the `mongo` gem fine, but when I try to install `nokogiri`, I get the following errors:

```
$ gem install nokogiri
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/johnsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for libxml/parser.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

After that message, it lists a whole bunch of configuration options, and then says:

```
/Users/johnsmith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:369:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
```

It seems that I have the development tools, so I can't figure out the problem. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I had to look around a while, but I found the solution at github:
https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/442#issuecomment-7978408

> libxml2 is missing.
>
> I found one extra step was required to solve the above for Homebrew
>   0.9 on Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion and that is to create a "/usr/bin/gcc-4.2" link:

```
brew install libxml2 libxslt
brew link libxml2 libxslt
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libiconv/libiconv-1.13.1.tar.gz
tar xvfz libiconv-1.13.1.tar.gz
cd libiconv-1.13.1
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1
make
sudo make install
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.8.0/include/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.8.0/lib --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.26 --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/include --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need the development headers for libxml which are not provided as part of the compiler tools. Usually you will need to install one of [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) to help install these dependencies.

The hint here is somewhat hard to spot in the noise if you're not familiar, but is:

```
checking for libxml/parser.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
```

The `.h` files are provided with the development packages and are necessary to compile extensions against those libraries.

Comment: Thanks. I found the instructions on the Nokogiri site for installation with Homebrew 0.9, but still getting the same errors. Perhaps Homebrew 0.9.3 broke something else. I'll try MacPorts next.